# ASP MVC test project cascading delete instead of NO ACTION

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cascading-deletes

I have an unusual issue with deletes.  My model includes a contact table.  A contact may have deer_contacts_info or livestock_contacts_info.  The SQL express option is set to “no action”, in other words, prevent the shared data from being deleted if it has any child rows in other tables.  It will not delete if there is either deer or livestock data.  The SQL express option is set to “no action”, in other words, prevent the shared data from being deleted if it has any child rows in other tables.

Example:

- Contact 96 has both livestock and deer farm data.
- The user selects deer farm and deletes 96.
- Result: only the deer farm data is deleted.  The shared contact data is preserved along with its livestock row.
- The user selects livestock and deletes 96.
- Result: since livestock is the only child row, shared data will be deleted along with it.  No data will be remaining for 96.

This scenario works fine in the MVC web application.  Oddly enough, a test project does not produce the correct result.

Example:

- Contact 96 has both livestock and deer farm data.
- The test project selects deer farm and deletes 96.
- Result: all data is deleted, including livestock.  This was a cascading delete, which is not the desired result.

Here is a code snippet from the delete method of the controller:

```
if (contactType == Globals.getLivestockType())
    try
    {
        livestock_contacts_info livestock_contacts_info = db.livestock_contacts_info.Find(id);

        if (livestock_contacts_info != null)
        {
            db.livestock_contacts_info.Remove(livestock_contacts_info);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        CSession["message"] = "Error deleting livestock information for contact_id" + id;
        return RedirectToAction("ListContacts");
    }
else if (contactType == Globals.getDeerFarmType())
    try
    {
        deer_contacts_info deer_contacts_info = db.deer_contacts_info.Find(id);

        if (deer_contacts_info != null)
        {
            db.deer_contacts_info.Remove(deer_contacts_info);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        CSession["message"] = "Error deleting deer contact information for contact_id" + id;
        return RedirectToAction("ListContacts");
    }

/* after deleting subject specific data, attempt to delete shared data.  Shared data will not be deleted
    If it has any subject data remaining.
    */
try
{
    contact contact = db.contacts.Find(id);
    if (contact == null)
    {
        CSession["message"] = "contact " + id + " doesn't exist";
    }
    else
    {
        db.contacts.Remove(contact);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ListContacts");
}
```

I looked into the definition of contact to try to understand what was going on.  Here it is:

```
public partial class contact
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CONTACT_ID { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[^;]{0,100}$", ErrorMessage="This text field has unacceptable characters")]    /* ; not allowed */
    public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string MIDDLE_NAME { get; set; }
    public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string BUSINESS_NAME { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS1 { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS2 { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    public string STATE { get; set; }
    public string ZIP_CODE { get; set; }
    public string COUNTRY { get; set; }
    public string TELEPHONE1 { get; set; }
    public string TELEPHONE2 { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9-]{0,10}$", ErrorMessage="Please use only digits and dashes, with a maximum length of 10")]
    public string CELL_PHONE { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EMAIL_ADDRESS { get; set; }
    public string COMMENTS { get; set; }

    public virtual deer_contacts_info deer_contacts_info { get; set; }
    public virtual livestock_contacts_info livestock_contacts_info { get; set; }
}
```

The code snippet deletes the deer farm and livestock data first, then shared contacts.  In the shared contact delete section of the code, I compared the contents of class for the two tests:  For the web MVC test, both `deer_contacts_info` and `livestock_contacts_info` were null.  However, the test project test had non null contents.  Then I revised the code to make them both null.  The result was unchanged: the test project does a cascading delete.  Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: Please fix your tags: this is not asp-classic.

Comment: Hi Martha, thanks for your inquiry.  This is not classic ASP, this is MVC.